# sum of four squares with some coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there an ordered 4-tuple of rational numbers $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $(b,d)\ne(0,0)$ and $2a^2+3b^2+30c^2+45d^2=2$?

The former (deleted) question was just about cases $(a,b,c,d)\ne(1,0,0,0)$ but it was quite silly :( I apologize and I think now it makes sense. I guess there is a canonical proof of nonexistence or an algorithm for examples.

Comment: More interesting getting a parameterization of the solutions to this equation.  $$aX^2+bY^2+cZ^2+dR^2=jR^2$$  It is always better to get the formula in General.  The formulation of the problem is better like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually infinitely many, and a parametrization of all rational solutions is e.g.

$a:=\frac{3B^2+30C^2+45D^2-2E^2}{3B^2+30C^2+45D^2+2E^2}$

$b:=\frac{4BE}{3B^2+30C^2+45D^2+2E^2}$

$c:=\frac{4CE}{3B^2+30C^2+45D^2+2E^2}$

$d:=\frac{4DE}{3B^2+30C^2+45D^2+2E^2}$.

Comment: thank you very much! :D I guess I can easily generalize this parametrization to many similar cases.

Comment: Yes, you have a rational point -- here (1,0,0,0), so any rational line to it meets your quadric in another rational point.

Comment: Such a representation similar to equation.  $$aX^2+bY^2+cZ^2+dW^2=aR^2$$  You can write the parameterization of the solutions.  $$X=bp^2+cs^2+dt^2-ak^2$$  $$Y=2akp$$  $$Z=2aks$$  $$W=2akt$$  $$R=bp^2+cs^2+dt^2+ak^2$$

Answer (score 4):

First, one doesn't normally call $(a,b,c,d)$ a "pair" of rational numbers. In any case, first check that your equation has a solution with $(b,d)\ne0$ in $\mathbb R$ (which it clearly does) and in $\mathbb Q_p$ for every $p$. For the latter, it suffices (I think) to check $p=2,3,5$, since your form is non-singular for higher $p$. (But you might need to check a few more primes.) Assuming that there are such solutions, Minkowski's theorem will tell you that there is a solution in $\mathbb Q$. And of course, if you find a $\mathbb Q_p$ with no such solutions, then there are no $\mathbb Q$ solutions.

Comment: yeah, I'm not an English speaker in everyday speech, so my linguistic intuition is strange sometimes. anyway.. thanks! I'm a newcomer to this topic, and it seems I need to learn a lot first.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html). Lemma 2.7 on page 60 says that any quadratic form with rational coefficients ( well, nonzero determinant...) in five or more variables is isotropic in all $\mathbb Q_p$ for $p \neq \infty$

In addition, your form 
$$ 2 a^2 + 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2 - 2 e^2 $$
is indefinite, meaning $\infty$ is not a problem either. Pietro gave you all rational solutions parametrized, for your original problem. The interesting, and difficult, part is to rewrite these as primitive integer
solutions to the problem as I wrote it; here primitive means $\gcd(a,b,c,d,e) = 1.$ The type of answer depends heavily on dimension, I do not believe I have done a dimension five before. Take me some time.

Hmmmm. Could be elementary because of the repeated $2.$ $e^2 - a^2 \neq 2 \pmod 4,$ therfore $2 e^2 - 2 a^2 \neq 4 \pmod 8.$ So, pick any integers $b,c,d$ such that $b \equiv d \pmod 2$ BUT $3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2 \neq 4 \pmod 8,$ then solve
$$ e^2 - a^2 = \frac{3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2}{2} $$
by factoring the right hand side and finding all divisor pairs as $(e+a)$ and $(e-a).$ Close enough for government work.

Extra annoyance: the condition $b \equiv d \pmod 2$ directly implies $3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2 \neq 4 \pmod 8,$ so the only requirement is $b \equiv d \pmod 2$

```
30  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  1   b: 0   c: 1   d: 0   e: 4
30  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  7   b: 0   c: 1   d: 0   e: 8
42  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  10   b: 2   c: 1   d: 0   e: 11
42  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  2   b: 2   c: 1   d: 0   e: 5
48  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  1   b: 1   c: 0   d: 1   e: 5
48  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  1   b: 4   c: 0   d: 0   e: 5
48  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  5   b: 1   c: 0   d: 1   e: 7
48  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  5   b: 4   c: 0   d: 0   e: 7
72  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  0   b: 3   c: 0   d: 1   e: 6
72  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  8   b: 3   c: 0   d: 1   e: 10
78  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  19   b: 1   c: 1   d: 1   e: 20
78  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  19   b: 4   c: 1   d: 0   e: 20
78  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  5   b: 1   c: 1   d: 1   e: 8
78  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  5   b: 4   c: 1   d: 0   e: 8
102  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  25   b: 3   c: 1   d: 1   e: 26
102  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  7   b: 3   c: 1   d: 1   e: 10
120  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  14   b: 5   c: 0   d: 1   e: 16
120  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  2   b: 5   c: 0   d: 1   e: 8
138  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  10   b: 6   c: 1   d: 0   e: 13
138  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  34   b: 6   c: 1   d: 0   e: 35
150  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  11   b: 5   c: 1   d: 1   e: 14
150  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  37   b: 5   c: 1   d: 1   e: 38
150  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  5   b: 5   c: 1   d: 1   e: 10
168  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  20   b: 1   c: 2   d: 1   e: 22
168  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  4   b: 1   c: 2   d: 1   e: 10
192  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  10   b: 3   c: 2   d: 1   e: 14
192  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  10   b: 7   c: 0   d: 1   e: 14
192  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  23   b: 2   c: 0   d: 2   e: 25
192  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  23   b: 3   c: 2   d: 1   e: 25
192  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  23   b: 7   c: 0   d: 1   e: 25
192  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  23   b: 8   c: 0   d: 0   e: 25
192  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  2   b: 3   c: 2   d: 1   e: 10
192  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  2   b: 7   c: 0   d: 1   e: 10
192  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  5   b: 2   c: 0   d: 2   e: 11
192  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  5   b: 3   c: 2   d: 1   e: 11
192  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  5   b: 7   c: 0   d: 1   e: 11
192  was 3 b^2 + 30 c^2 + 45 d^2      a:  5   b: 8   c: 0   d: 0   e: 11
```